# column value is not increment after 10

Tags: mysql, functions, sequence

I tried below 2 codes.... showing same error

1.`SELECT columnname FROM tablename ORDER BY columnname DESC LIMIT 1`

2. `SELECT MAX(columnname ) AS max FROM tablename`

I am trying to increment value of column.(`++string`) It worked properly till `10`. After 10 it is not increment.

then i checked manually, then i get result `9`.

> Result Got - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 10 10 10
>
> Result Required - 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12

I think database `count 10 as 1`. i dont know why?

In future i want change number to string like... pro1, pro2 like that..so that i dont want to change datatype

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have your column data-type on non numeric format. if your data type is `CHAR` (or `VARCHAR`) type it would select **9** as your max number.

If you **change your datatype for the column to `INT`**, your problem should be resolved.

Comment: i thought that already, in future i want change number to string like... pro1, pro2 like that..so i cant change datatype

Comment: @Prashant if you want your data to behave like numbers (i.e. show correctly maximum and minimum, do increments/decrements), use a number datatype, as this answer suggests. Not chars.

Comment: @ypercube : check my edited question.

Comment: It doesn't make any more sense. Don't do that, not now, not in the future. If your requirements are to store numbers as strings, change them. They are not sane requirements. I'm sure the underneath problem can be solved in some other manner.

Comment: @ypercube i did, but problem not solved

Comment: Do some form of concatenation. Use auto_increment for your integer part f1 - define your string part as VARCHAR(3) (or whatever) f2 and then use a trigger to concatenate them to another string SELECT CONCAT(f1, f2) and put them in f3. Don't forget that (string) 001 != 1 - got bitten by that many moons ago - legacy system (still have bad dreams and night sweats!).